# want to know where i can verify if my system was cloned without my knowledge

Tags: windows, disk-cloning

Hi I followed instuctions to restore my gateway updater but when I tried it again it's still not going through. It's just trying to check for updates then stops without saying no updates are available can you help me regarding this to be able to check for updates?

And also another concern is that I went to event viewer and found this log as critical error event id 8193 source was system restore and it was regarding gateway updater. I tried looking online and found [this website](http://www.eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=8193&eventno=9479&source=SystemRestore&phase=1) which explains why my updater is not working.

I was wondering if you could check that website and help me figure what it was trying to explain about error in cloning my drives which I have never done myself. but still concerned if someone tried using my computer and did that cloning and if there is a way to find out if my system is cloned. just to check if my computer was ever cloned without me knowing

Comment: You might be interested in reading the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq)

Answer (score 1):

You are being paranoid with this 'clone' reference. as @pacey mentioned, this has to do with your restore points.  I personally just disable windows restore (have never had a need to use it and have heard issues with viruses etc being stored in them).

My recommendation, disable restore point http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310405

Also taking a 'copy' of your hdd could be done without any log entries, as this would be a clone of your hard drive (ala say Norton Ghost) but that is not what is going on here, just a simple log error.

Comment: Yup, it's impossible to tell from the OS whether a drive was cloned, since this is done below the OS level anyway.

Comment: System Restore has saved my bacon more than once, key is to use disk cleanup to delete all but the last restore point occasionally

Answer (score 0):

This error occured while trying to create a Restore Point. Many Updates for Microsoft Windows create Restore Points unless otherwise configured for your safety. So if anything goes wrong with an update you can just restore to the state your computer was in before you installed the Update.

Let's say you install a new driver for your graphics adapter, and you have chosen the wrong driver version and your system won't display anything on your screen. With RestorePoints Windows gives you the ability to revert your computer to the state before you installed that driver.